# openvr actions are not active

Tags: python, steamvr, openvr

im trying to get the action binding working.

steamvr doesn't seam to recognise the "new input method" in the steamvr console, but all the bindings get loaded correctly but dont get bound, and binding the with the ui still doesn't produce outputs
no errors are thrown, and the actions aren't active and just return empty data (all 0)

```
{
  "default_bindings": [
    {
      "controller_type": "knuckles",
      "binding_url": "binding_knuckles.json"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/actions/Dragger/in/hand_pos",
      "requirement": "optional",
      "type": "pose"
    },
    {
      "name": "/actions/Dragger/in/a_butt",
      "requirement": "optional",
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  ],
  "localization": [
    {
      "language_tag": "en_us",
      "/actions/Dragger/in/hand_pos": "poseable",
      "/actions/Dragger/in/a_butt": "abutt"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
 "bindings": {
  "/actions/Dragger": {
   "poses": [
    {
     "output": "/actions/Dragger/in/hand_pos",
     "path": "/user/hand/left/pose/raw"
    }
   ],
   "haptics": [],
   "sources": [
    {
     "inputs": {
      "click": {
       "output": "/actions/Dragger/in/a_butt"
      }
     },
     "mode": "button",
     "path": "/user/hand/left/input/b"
    }
   ]
  }
 },
 "cords": {},
 "controller_type": "knuckles"
}
```

```
import os, time, openvr

openvr.init(openvr.VRApplication_Scene)
openvr.VRInput().setActionManifestPath(os.path.abspath("manifests/manifest.json"))
actionset = openvr.VRInput().getActionSetHandle("/actions/Dragger")
action_hide_cubes = openvr.VRInput().getActionHandle("/actions/Dragger/in/a_butt")
action_hand = openvr.VRInput().getActionHandle("/actions/Dragger/in/hand_pos")

print("running")
for i in range(100000):

    action_sets = (openvr.VRActiveActionSet_t * 1)()
    action_set = action_sets[0]
    action_set.ulActionSet = actionset
    openvr.VRInput().updateActionState(action_sets)

    action_data = openvr.VRInput().getDigitalActionData(action_hide_cubes, openvr.k_ulInvalidInputValueHandle)
    if action_data.bActive:
        print("can be clicked")
        if action_data.bState:
            print("has been click")

    action_data = openvr.VRInput().getPoseActionDataForNextFrame(action_hand, openvr.TrackingUniverseRawAndUncalibrated
                                                                 ,   openvr.k_ulInvalidInputValueHandle)
    if action_data.bActive:
        print("hand pos:", action_data.pose.mDeviceToAbsoluteTracking)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print()
    print("-----------")
openvr.shutdown()
print("shutdown")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
    if action_data.bActive:
        print("clicked")
```

From [`ValveSoftware/openvr/headers/openvr.h`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/15f0838a0487feb7da60acd39aab8099b994234c/headers/openvr.h#L4968-L4974), `bActive` means "Whether or not this action is currently available to be bound in the active action set"

It does not mean "clicked".

For that, you would need to use `bState`:

> The current state of this action; will be true if currently pressed

That is, in your case:

```py
    if action_data.bActive and action_data.bState:
        print("Button pressed")
```

> all data `bActive`, `bState` always being 0, `action_data.pose.mDeviceToAbsoluteTracking` is all 0 to. all data is 0

Make sure that your JSON files are valid. You can use online JSON validators to check for syntax errors.

Use the [SteamVR binding UI](https://valvesoftware.github.io/steamvr_unity_plugin/tutorials/SteamVR-Input.html#binding-actions) to make sure your actions are correctly set up and bound to the controller inputs. Sometimes, manually setting up bindings through this interface can resolve recognition issues.

Double-check the content of the [SteamVR Input guide](https://valvesoftware.github.io/steamvr_unity_plugin/tutorials/SteamVR-Input.html#overview).

---

> looks like there was two issues.
>
> - using `action_set` instead of `action_sets`.
> - and the workshop replacing "`/actions/Dragger`" with "`/actions/dragger`" in some place.

True:  `action_sets` is an array of `VRActiveActionSet_t`, which allows you to update and manage multiple action sets simultaneously. The proper handling of this array is essential for OpenVR to correctly process which actions are active and should be listened for.
usage:

```py
action_sets = (openvr.VRActiveActionSet_t * 1)()
action_set = action_sets[0]
action_set.ulActionSet = actionset
openvr.VRInput().updateActionState(action_sets)
```

Regarding the case sensitivity in action paths, if the action paths do not match exactly between your code, manifest, and binding files, OpenVR will not recognize them as the same action. That can lead to actions not being triggered or recognized.
Make sure the action paths are consistently named across all your files. The case (uppercase vs. lowercase) must match exactly. Consistency in naming conventions should help prevent such issues.

Comment: this dosnt solve the problem of all data bActive, bState always being 0.

Comment: action_data.pose.mDeviceToAbsoluteTracking is all 0 to. all data is 0. im looking for how to make steamvr recocnise and bind the "new input"

Comment: @ellieff1493 My point was: if you only test bActive, it does not indicate "pressed" or "not pressed".

Comment: @ellieff1493 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: ahhhh, it wasnt anyof this, but after 2 weeks of debuging and not even changing the code a single bit, its now working. my guess it was the workshop casheing it badly or something

Comment: @ellieff1493 Great, good news. I will leave my answer for others to use.

Comment: looks like there was two issues. using action_set instead of action_sets. and the workshop replacing "/actions/Dragger" with "/actions/dragger" in some place. still investigation the second one but it looks like largely a none issue aslong as i type "action_sets" right

Comment: @ellieff1493 Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to reflect your conclusion.